# vim c/c++ ftplugin scripts

Tags: vim, vimrc

I make some additions to the regular runtime in my vim configuration. I add to `rtp` a directory where there are `ftplugin` directory, in which I have two files: `c.vim` and `cpp.vim`. In these files I determine a couple commands with the same name but different content which depends on the file, is it c and cpp file.

In c.vim:

```
execute "nnoremap <silent> ".g:formatterTrigger." :call Formatters#Uncrustify#C()<Cr>"
```

In cpp.vim:

```
execute "nnoremap <silent> ".g:formatterTrigger." :call Formatters#Uncrustify#Cpp()<Cr>"
```

But I see by `scriptnames` command that both these ft files are loaded. And the c.vim is loaded the first so in cpp files I have c commands. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `runtimepath` for that, the `after` directory (`:h after-directory`) is what you need.

Place those two files in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`.

Comment: The problem is that vim loads both c.vim and cpp.vim for cpp sources.

Comment: Did you try it before writing that comment? Since you use the same shortcut (`g:formatterTrigger`), the cpp mapping overwrites the c mapping so you get *only* the cpp mapping in cpp and *only* the c mapping in c.

Answer (score 0):

Due to their similarity, the *cpp* filetype is based on the *c* one. Therefore, both files are sourced, as you've noted. But that's no problem, because the *cpp* one comes last, and will override the *c* one; you can check with

```
:verbose execute 'nnoremap' g:formatterTrigger
```

In general, this is nothing to worry about (unless you define `:map <unique>`, which would complain in that case), and you already know the commands like `:scriptnames` to troubleshoot this issue.